# Удаление элемента из массива javascript

Tags: javascript, функциональное-программирование

Нужна функция `removeArray(x, n)`, которая удаляет n из массива и извлекает полученный элемент. Например:

```
var y = [2,3,4];
y = removeArray(y, 1)
console.log(y) //выведет [2, 4]
```

Вот функция:

```
function removeArray(x, n) {
    for(let i = 0; i < x.length;i++) {
        x.splice(x[i],n)

    }
}

console.log(removeArray([2,3,4], 1))
```

В консоли печатает undefined. 
Это правильное решение?

Comment: А зачем вам цикл for?

Comment: для получения каждова элемента в массиве,нет?

Comment: А зачем каждый, если нужен только под номером n?

Comment: А можете предложит свой вариант решения,чтоб мне была ясно?

Comment: _это правильное решение?_ - если решение дает неверный ответ, очевидно, решение не верное

Comment: Одна функция splice делает ведь всё, что нужно - и удаляет, и возвращает удалённое как результат

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления элемента из середины массива существует встроенная функция `splice`.

```
var y = [2, 3, 4];
var e = y.splice(1, 1)
console.log(y)
```

В `e` будет лежать массив удалённых символов. Если надо, чтобы была строка, используйте метод `join`.

```
console.log(e.join(""))
```